# How to implement a chat feature on Laravel Application?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, chat

## I have

a web-application that use :

- **Laravel** for the back-end
- **Angular** for the front-end.

---

## I finished

implement the whole

#### user-authentication

- register
- log-in/log-out
- forgot-password
- reset-password
- email activation

---

## Now, I want

to add a chat feature to allow my users to chat with each other.

[image]

How do we make something like that ? How do we start ?
For anyone that have done this, how did you start ?

Any hints or suggestions on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: This question...sigh.  There are countless tutorials on making chat features in angular.  So I'd start with Google.

Answer (score 2):

Actually chat application should not be done in pure PHP i would build chat application on the top of socket.io

https://github.com/krimple/angular-socketio-chat and pushing messages from laravel to socket.io client (angular)

http://www.codetutorial.io/laravel-5-and-socket-io-tutorial/